# How to write this Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to break the string into words by a hyphen. For example:

"WorkInProgress" is converted to "Work-In-Progress"

"NotComplete" is converted to "Not-Complete"

Most of cases one word starts with capital and ends with lowercase.

But there is one exception, "CIInProgress" should be converted to "CI-In-Progress".

I wrote like the code below, any pattern that has lowercase or "CI", followed by an capital, will be added "-" in middle. But it still can't work for "CIInProgress". Can anyone tell me how to correct it?

```
String str;
String pattern = "([a-z|CI]+)([A-Z])";
str= str.replaceAll(pattern, "$1\\-$2");
```

Comment: You must understand that a character class is only a collection of characters, but not a collection of substrings. `[A|BC]` means "A" or "|" or "B" or "C" and is the same as `[B|CA]` or `[|CBA]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind,

**Regex:**

```
(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z])
```

**Replacement string:**

```
-$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/2)

**Explanation:**

`(?<!^)` Negative lookbehind is used here , which asserts what proceeds the characters `[A-Z]`(uppercase) and also the following  `[a-z]`(lowercase) is not a starting anchor. An uppercase letter and the following lowercase letter will be matched only if it satisfies the above mentioned condition.`()` capturing groups are used to capture the matched characters, captured chars are stored into groups. Later you could get the captured chars by referring it's group index number.

**Code:**

```
System.out.println("WorkInProgress".replaceAll("(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z])", "-$1"));
System.out.println("NotComplete".replaceAll("(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z])", "-$1"));
System.out.println("CIInProgress".replaceAll("(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z])", "-$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
Work-In-Progress
Not-Complete
CI-In-Progress
```

Comment: This is a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `|` in a character class; it will just get interpreted as a literal vertical bar character. Try:

```
String pattern = "([a-z]+|CI)([A-Z])";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    str= str.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{javaLowerCase})(?=\\p{javaUpperCase})", "-");
```

Comment: I didn't know these character classes!

Comment: Any method which starts with "is" in Character class can be used as \p{javaMethodNameWithoutIs} in Java regex

Comment: Thanks Евгений Онегин (Eugène Onéguine) :), it's a great mnemonic tool.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev your regex won't work for this `CIInProgress` input.